# How to incorporate Eloquent API resource with Spatie QueryBuilder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In reading through the QueryBuilder docs and other blog posts, I see references to [using Eloquent API resources](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v5/features/including-relationships#content-eloquent-api-resources), but they are just a reference with no details. What I am trying to understand is how to use a collection for the primary model being returned, not just for a relationship inside that resource.

For instance, here is a query that returns a model called `WorkHours`:

```
 return Inertia::render('Users/WorkHours/Index', [
            'workHours' => QueryBuilder::for(WorkHours::class)
                ->where('user_id', $user->id)
                ->with('area')
                ->allowedIncludes(['area'])
                ->allowedSorts('date')
                ->defaultSort('-date')
                ->allowedFilters([
                    AllowedFilter::callback('year', function(Builder $query, $value) {
                        $thirdSaturdayPrevious = Carbon::parse('Third Saturday of April ' . $value-1)->toDateString();
                        $thirdSaturdayThis = Carbon::parse('Third Saturday of April ' . $value)->toDateString();
                        $query->whereBetween('date', [$thirdSaturdayPrevious, $thirdSaturdayThis]);
                    })
                ])
                ->paginate(20)
                ->withQueryString(),
            'user' => new UserResource($user),
            'areas' => Area::with('approvers')->get()
        ]);
```

Before implementing QueryBuilder, I was using this:

```
 'workHours' => WorkHoursResource::collection(WorkHours::where('user_id', $user->id)
               ->where('approved', true)
               ->with(['approver', 'area', 'user'])->get()),
```

and I would do stuff like converting boolean values to `Yes` or `No` in my resource.

What I can't figure out is how to use my `WorkHoursResource` for the returned `WorkHours` items. I can't wrap the whole item, since that returns all of the pagination meta data, and I've tried using `WorkHoursResource` at various places in the query, but no dice.

Is it even possible to use a resource for the main QueryBuilder item, the `workHours` records in this case?

Comment: Can you try to execute query and pass result in you resource. Imagine
`workHours = query` and then  `return Inertia::render('Users/WorkHours/Index', [ 'workHours' => workHourResource::collection(workHours)´])`;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [AI Larry at Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-incorporate-eloquent-api-resource-with-spatie-querybuilder?page=1&replyId=894610), I found out all I had to do was wrap the query with my collection.

```
'workHours' => WorkHoursResource::collection(
                QueryBuilder::for(WorkHours::class)
                    ->where('user_id', $user->id)
                    ->with('area')
                    ->allowedIncludes(['area'])
                    ->allowedSorts('date')
                    ->defaultSort('-date')
                    ->allowedFilters([
                        AllowedFilter::callback('year', function(Builder $query, $value) {
                            $thirdSaturdayPrevious = Carbon::parse('Third Saturday of April ' . $value-1)->toDateString();
                            $thirdSaturdayThis = Carbon::parse('Third Saturday of April ' . $value)->toDateString();
                            $query->whereBetween('date', [$thirdSaturdayPrevious, $thirdSaturdayThis]);
                        })
                    ])
                    ->paginate(20)
                    ->withQueryString()),
```

I swear I tried that, but I must have typoed somwhere.